# How to toggle enable/disable words and phrases in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress.com, text

Is it possible to disable phrases on a WordPress blog post? I have some information on that post that I don't want to show it for the moment - I will show it next year.

I know that I can copy that phrase somewhere in a text file on my computer and then paste it on the WordPress blog post next year but that's really complicated:

- I have multiple phrases that I have to disable. That means a lot of cut-paste work today and a lot of copy-paste work next year
- I want to do that in many blog posts, and that means ever more work
- It is possible that I lose that text file that contains the phrases, so it's much better to have them saved somewhere online

Therefore it's much better to just disable those phrases now, and enable them later when I have to display them.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this plugin: [Hide This - by Andrés Villarreal](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-this/) but I just noticed that only paid hosting can try plugins on Wordpress.com